# Is it ok to copy css from different sites?

Tags: html, css

Is it ok to copy css from different sites ?

I mean say I have copied navigation menu css from one site, sidebar css from other, button css from another, footer from another and so on...

Could I get in legal trouble for such kind of copying ??

Update : I thought it would make more sense if instead I showed you the design itself :)

[image]

Comment: Why not?I think it is fine!That's the beauty of Web.

Comment: You should ask a lawyer.

Comment: Most sites have a license at the bottom. That should explain everything you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you also copy graphic design (`background-image: url(img/bg-border-top.png);`) definitely yes, you' re in legal trouble.

If you copy CSS without the images, you *could* have problems, IANAL, depending on your country, the sites you're stealing from and their respective country, etc
Using the same technique is perfectly OK (that is, parts of parts of CSS like CSS sprites here, accordion menu there, etc)

Now WHY? There are dozens of CSS frameworks, hundreds of templates and designs under licences like **GPL** or **Creative Commons-Attribution** (with derivatives and commercial use allowed) so why would you even care to take any risk copying (*verbatim*) CSS their authors don't want you to copy?
And for only $39, this WordPress theme is yours for the next 24H (entirely made of `div` yay! </joking>)

Answer (score 2):

You can use everything on web that allows you to copy and paste, except images, videos, and content because this can have copyright issues.

For copying CSS, JavaScript, jQuery.... you are free to use it :)